# printing C string after 0 terminating it

Tags: c

```
int main(void) {
   // your code goes here
   char* qwe = "qwe";
   qwe[2] = '\0';
   printf("%s\n", qwe);
   return 0;
}
```

I been messing with C pointers to see if I understand them correctly. 
From the code, `qwe` contains `char` pointers to
letter `'q', and can reach to 'w', 'e'`, and `'\0'`. `qwe[2] = *(qwe + 2)`, which is `e`. I terminated it with `'\0'`. Now it is giving me a segmentation fault when I try to print it. I was expecting the output `qw`.

Comment: Not all memory addresses are writable, one case is the address for which the compiler assigned for your string literal.

Comment: No, `qwe` is a **pointer**. It is not called "array" for reasons you find in every good C book and tutorial. (And an _array_ is also not a pointer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get segmentation fault not because of printing, but because you try to make a write into memory of a *string literal*. If you make a copy into writable memory, your code would work:

```
int main(void) {
   char qwe[] = "qwe";
   //   ^^^^^
   qwe[2] = '\0';
   printf("%s\n", qwe); // prints "qw"
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The reason you can't modify a string literal is because the compiler could place it in the code segment.  The `char` array is data like other local variables.

Comment: I see, What should I research to understand this concept more? Was my question not clear enough that it deserve a thumbs down?

Comment: @lostdong12 There is no special concept, string literals are a special case in the language. Moreover, your code would work on many compilers despite undefined behavior, which makes the program ill-formed. Generally, undefined behavior is worth reading about to understand how the same program could work on some systems, and break on other systems. As far as downvotes go, I do not think it's entirely fair, because this behavior is not easy to understand.

Comment: @e0k: No. The reason you **must** not modify a string literal is because it invokes _undefined behaviour_. Where it is effectively placed is not dictated by the C standard. An implementation is free to store it where it likes. Some very well put it into normal RAM. And the `char []` actually **is** a local variable, not just "like".